# Why Might Python Be Running Slow

Tags: python, performance, tensorflow

I am trying to run a program I created that uses a neural network to predict stock prices.  I am trying to run it for a number of various different stocks.  I am running the same exact code on both my desktop and my laptop.

At first I was running the code only on my desktop, and it was running very slow.  At first I thought it was just because of the number of calculations to be made for the neural network.  However, I also started running the code on my laptop to be able to run it for two stocks at the same time.

The code runs much much faster on my laptop (I would estimate about 20x faster), even though my desktop has a much better processor, GPU, etc...  I am also using the same size data set for each run as well.

I added the lines of code:

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"  
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = ""
```

So that python should be using my processor and not my graphics processor, I am not sure if that makes a difference.

Any idea why this might be?

Comment: What other differences can you identify between the two environments? As a sanity check - are you using the same data? Do you get the same result?

Comment: +1 to above, also are you using a framework, e.g. PyTorch, Tensorflow? It might be that it can't communicate with your GPU and so you are seeing CPU performance. You can check this with your framework, e.g. for PyTorch `torch.cuda.is_available()`

Comment: Hi, yes I am using tensorflow.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, I tried running the same data for both my desktop and my laptop.  My desktop still ran much slower than my laptop.

Comment: My laptop does not have a graphics processor, but my desktop does.  Could it be something with the communication between the CPU and GPU on my desktop?

Comment: If you **remove** the CUDA statements, does it go faster or slower on your desktop? And on your laptop? (To figure out if it is using gpu). [And you need to respond to the **first comment**. Python versions? OS versions?]  **EDIT** Actually, its probably **something else running on your desktop**. Maybe boot in `safe mode`, or otherwise **disable all startup** software, try again.

Comment: The first thing I would do is run the code in a profiler, otherwise its very easy to make assumptions which lead you in the wrong direction. [cProfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#the-python-profilers) is very straightforward to use and should give you an idea where the disparity in performance is.